# a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session in case of saveOrUpdateAll in Hibernate3

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa, hibernate-mapping

In case of modify it's giving `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException`.
In my BidderBO class

```
@Override
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public boolean updateBidder(BiddersDetailForm bidderDetailForm, MISSessionBean misSessionBean) throws MISException {
    boolean status = false;
    boolean childStatus =false;
    try {
        BidderHeaderBean bidderHeaderBean = populaBidderHeaderBean(bidderDetailForm);

        MISAuditBean misAuditBean = new MISAuditBean();
        misAuditBean.setStatus(MISConstants.MASTER_STATUS_VERIFIED);
        misAuditBean.setEntBy(misSessionBean.getEnteredBy());
        misAuditBean.setEntDate(misSessionBean.getEnteredDate());
        bidderHeaderBean.setMisAuditBean(misAuditBean);

        status = bidderHeaderDao.updateBidderHeader(bidderHeaderBean);

        if(status){
            long bidderInfoId = bidderDetailForm.getBidInfoId();
            List<BidderDetailBean> bidderDetailBeans = populateBidderDetailBeans(bidderDetailForm, bidderInfoId,  misSessionBean, MISConstants.MASTER_STATUS_VERIFIED);
            log.debug("\nBidder DetailBeans\t"+bidderDetailBeans);
            for(BidderDetailBean bidderDetailBean:bidderDetailBeans ){
                log.debug("bank name  ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getBankName());
                log.debug("bid amount ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getBidAmount());
                log.debug("getBidderName ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getBidderName());
                log.debug("getBidInfoId ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getBidInfoId());
                log.debug("getSeqBidId ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getSeqBidId());
                log.debug("status ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getMisAuditBean().getStatus());
                log.debug("bid sale date ==========="+bidderDetailBean.getMisAuditBean().getEntDate());

                }
            childStatus = bidderDetailDao.updateBidderDetailBeans(bidderDetailBeans);
            if(!childStatus){
                throw new MISException(MISExceptionCodes.MIS003, "Bidder Details are not updated for "+bidderDetailForm.getTenderId());
            }

        }
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
        throw new MISException(e.getMostSpecificCause());
    } catch (MISException e) {
        log.error(e.getLocalizedMessage(),e);
        throw e;
    }
    return status && childStatus;
}
```

and Bean (BidderDetailBean) is

```
public class BidderDetailBean implements Serializable {


/**
 * Initial Version
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -2234569083113434751L;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "seq_bid_id", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_bid_id", sequenceName = "prwss_main.seq_bid_id")
@Column(name = "seq_bid_id", nullable = false)
private long seqBidId;


@Column(name="bid_info_id", nullable=false)
private long bidInfoId;


@Column(name="bidder_name", nullable=false)
private String bidderName;

@Column(name="bid_sale_date")
private Date bidSaleDate;

@Column(name="bid_submitted")
private String bidSubmitted;

@Column(name="emd_amount")
private double emdAmount;

@Column(name="emd_valid_upto")
private Date emdValidUpto;

@Column(name="emd_instrument_type")
private String emdInstrumentType;

@Column(name="bank_name")
private String bankName;

@Column(name="not_responsive")
private String notResponsive;

@Column(name="bidder_contact_number")
private String contactNumber;

@Column(name="remarks")
private String remarks;

@Column(name="bid_amount")
private double bidAmount;

@Embedded
private MISAuditBean misAuditBean;

public long getBidInfoId() {
    return bidInfoId;
}

public void setBidInfoId(long bidInfoId) {
    this.bidInfoId = bidInfoId;
}

public String getBidderName() {
    return bidderName;
}

public void setBidderName(String bidderName) {
    this.bidderName = bidderName;
}

public Date getBidSaleDate() {
    return bidSaleDate;
}

public void setBidSaleDate(Date bidSaleDate) {
    this.bidSaleDate = bidSaleDate;
}
```

.................................

and BidderHeaderBean  is .....

```
public class BidderHeaderBean implements Serializable {

/**
 * Initial Version
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6163541390640145180L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq_bid_info_id",      sequenceName="prwss_main.seq_bid_info_id")
@GeneratedValue(generator="seq_bid_info_id", strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="bid_info_id", nullable=false)
private long bidInfoId;

@Column(name="location_id")
private String locationId;

@Column(name="tender_id")
private String tenderId;

@Column(name="bidding_phase")
private int biddingPhase;

@Column(name="bid_opening_date")
private Date bidOpeningDate;

@Column(name="reference_tender_id")
private String referenceTenderId;

@Embedded
private MISAuditBean misAuditBean;

@OneToMany(targetEntity=BidderDetailBean.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="bid_info_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Set<BidderDetailBean> bidderDetailBeans;

public long getBidInfoId() {
    return bidInfoId;
}

public void setBidInfoId(long bidInfoId) {
    this.bidInfoId = bidInfoId;
}
```

and my daoimpl class i am using this function........

```
@Override
public boolean saveOrUpdateBidderDetailBeans(Collection<BidderDetailBean> bidderDetailBeans) throws DataAccessException {

    try {
        System.out.println("bidderDetailBeans----in dao===="+bidderDetailBeans.toString());
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdateAll(bidderDetailBeans);
        getHibernateTemplate().flush();
        getHibernateTemplate().clear();
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw e;
    }

    return true;
}
```

please give some guide i have also tried clear function and merge and saveOrUpdate but it's not working .
it's giving error ............

```
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bank name  ===========State Bank of Patiala
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid amount ===========1452250.0
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidderName ===========7575
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidInfoId ===========3517
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getSeqBidId ===========5268
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] status ===========U
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid sale date ===========2014-06-27 10:04:46.857
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bank name  ===========State Bank of Patiala
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid amount ===========992620.0
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidderName ===========Ven00002
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidInfoId ===========3517
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getSeqBidId ===========5267
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] status ===========D
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid sale date ===========2014-06-27 10:04:46.857
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bank name  ===========State Bank of Patiala
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid amount ===========1452250.0
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidderName ===========7575
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getBidInfoId ===========3517
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] getSeqBidId ===========5268
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] status ===========D
2014-06-27 10:10:08,659 DEBUG [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] bid sale date ===========2014-06-27 10:04:46.857
2014-06-27 10:10:08,667 ERROR [com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl] a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailBean#5268]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailBean#5268]
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateSystemException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailBean#5268]; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailBean#5268]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:679)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:411)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdateAll(HibernateTemplate.java:757)
    at com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailDaoImpl.saveOrUpdateBidderDetailBeans(BidderDetailDaoImpl.java:53)
    at com.prwss.mis.tender.BidderBOImpl.updateBidder(BidderBOImpl.java:131)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy34.updateBidder(Unknown Source)
    at com.prwss.mis.tender.struts.BiddersDetailAction.update(BiddersDetailAction.java:318)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.struts.DelegatingActionProxy.execute(DelegatingActionProxy.java:113)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.prwss.mis.tender.biddersdetail.dao.BidderDetailBean#5268]
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:638)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:673)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$18.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:761)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    ... 49 more
```

Answer (score 2):

This exception is thrown whenever you call saveOrUpdate (which means Session entity attachment) for an Entity that has been previously attached to the current Session.

A workaround is to use merge which attached an entity only if there is none already attached, in which case it simply merges the already attached one to the current Entity given as parameter.

BidderHeaderBean has a non insertable/updatable children association:

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity=BidderDetailBean.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="bid_info_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private Set<BidderDetailBean> bidderDetailBeans;
```

which is not a mappedBy or inverse one. BidderDetailBean doesn't have an association to the BidderHeaderBean either, so this association could never work, since the foreign key will never be inserted/updated.

Comment: Actually i am using saveOrUpdateAll not saveOrUpdate and i have also used merge but it gives org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: java.util.ArrayList

Comment: That exception can't be explained by your current mappings, since there is no ArrayList there.